# Regular n-simplex with unit n-volume

Tags: geometry, simplex

Given are the coordinates of a regular $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where all edge lengths are 1. For symmetry the vertices are centered on the origin.

The volume of that unit $n$-simplex is $V_n=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n! \sqrt{2^n}}$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Geometric_properties) for definitions and formulas).

As the $n$-simplex is centered we can multiply the coordinates by a factor $\alpha_n$ without changing symmetry. The factor only affects the volume. By which factor $\alpha_n$ the coordinates of an $n$-simplex have to be multiplied to get $V_n=1$?

The first (approximate) values are
$\alpha_1=1, \alpha_2\approx1.5194, \alpha_3\approx 2.0397, \alpha_4=2.5598$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume scales with the $n$th power of the scale factor, so $\alpha_n$ is the reciprocal of the $n$th root of the volume you know.